# Swift Package Issue after updating to MacOS Monterey

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I'm having this issue with my swift package. It was created a few weeks ago with BigSur, as the platform target i put iOS 15. I don't understand what it could be

`ld: warning: dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/pm/ManifestAPI/libPackageDescription.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.15)`

Comment: Go through all your Package files and Xcode targets and check the target versions for iOS and MacOS

Comment: The package made for ios only, in the package file i put only this platforms: [.iOS(.v15)]

Comment: And any other targets and/or packages? I would also make sure I have cleaned the build folder and also emptied the Derived Data folder before building with a new Xcode version.

Comment: Could it be a problem with Xcode command line tools?

Comment: No other targets or packages, this issue is on the actual package project.

Comment: It turned out to be a problem with Xcode command line tools, no idea what happened but now it's gone

Comment: @MattiaCintura Still facing it did you do anything to silent that warning?

Comment: @Sarath i've updated Xcode command line tools and changed deployment target

Comment: If the problem is solved, give an answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71762933/6479729 - this works for me

1. Enter this command in your terminal:

   sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
2. Relaunch Xcode

Comment: If there is allready an answer to the question you should mark it as duplicate.