# Swift Package: ld: warning: dylib was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.15)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I've been searching for solution to get rid of this warning error:

> ld: warning: dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDESwiftPackageCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SwiftPM.framework/SharedSupport/ManifestAPI/libPackageDescription.dylib) was built for newer macOS version (11.0) than being linked (10.15)

I tried to clean & build Xcode project but no luck

This warning error might appear to you after creating new swift package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only simple solution worked like magic is:

1. Enter this command in your terminal:

> sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app

2. Relaunch Xcode

Credit to Arturo: https://blog.arturofm.com/solve-warning-was-built-for-newer-macos-version-xcode/

I published his answer here because I was searching for weeks on Stack overflow but non of their solutions helped me.

Comment: Does work, abviously this also shouldn't work

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

Reset the package cache (`File -> Packages -> Reset Package Caches`) and clean your build folder (`Product -> Clean Build Folder`) and the warning should be gone.